# Is DynamicForm suitable for maximum customization of user interface?

Tags: smartgwt

What is the most flexible/suitable form/layout in SmartGWT, if i would like to customize my user interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic form should be used to create form.There are many controls you can use with it.
You can see the examples [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#main)

Comment: @user466825 You can also up vote the answer which u accepted.